# Unifying types of identical meanings

Tags: coq

I have this goal:

```
forall n m : nat, S n > m -> n >= m
```

The gt_S lemmata would be applicable to prove it but Coq won't unify the two types.

```
gt_S: forall n m : nat, S n > m -> n > m \/ m = n
```

What would be the simplest solution here (excluding lia)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use forward reasoning by using `apply .. in` rather than plain `apply`.

```
Goal forall n m : nat, S n > m -> n >= m.
Proof.
  intros n m h.
  apply gt_S in h.
```

After which hypothesis `h` is now `h : n > m \/ m = n`.
Hopefully you should be able to progress from there.